# Assign a shortcut to a function without creating a menu item

Tags: python, nuke

I would like to assign a shortcut to a function for `nuke` menu in The Foundry NUKE.

So far I'm doing it like this:

```
nuke.menu('Nuke').addCommand('customTools/do_this', 'do_This.doThis()', 'alt+u')
```

I would like to skip all the `nuke.menu` part and just assign `alt+u` shortcut to **do_This.doThis()**.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following method: (it works fine in NUKE 10.5v7 on macOS 10.11)

```
import nuke
import math

def doThat(a,b):
    c = a + b
    print(c)

nuke.menu('Nuke').addCommand('self', 'doThat(5,7)', 'alt+u')

# Result: <MenuItem object at 0x11eb54d50>
# doThat(5,7)
# 12
```

or this one:

```
nuke.menu('Nuke').addCommand('', 'doThat(5,7)', 'alt+u')

# Result: <MenuItem object at 0x11eb54d38>
# doThat(5,7)
# 12
```